# which form of the verb should be used in this particular case: 'работает' or 'рабо́тают'

Tags: грамматика

> в нашей компании работает 25 сотрудников

I have come accross this sentence and I have two question about this sentence.

first, I think the subject of the sentence is:

> 25 сотрудников

since, it is plural 3rd person, the verb sould be `рабо́тают` instead of  `работает`. Isn't it right ?

second, If we change the order of the word in this sentence, would the form of the verb change or not.

for instance:

> 25 сотрудников рабо́тают в нашей компании

Comment: This is similar to English, where you can sometimes choose whether you are talking about a single entity or a group of people. "The committee has/have reached a decision" - both variants are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

> В нашей компании работа**ет** 25 сотрудников.

and

> В нашей компании работа**ют** 25 сотрудников.

are acceptable.  In the former case the verb takes the 3rd person singular because you're talking of the **entire working force** as of *a single entity*.  The subject of the sentence then is thus perceived as singular and the verb agrees.

Similar expression: "На по́лке сто**яло** пять кружек".  More examples can be found on the Web, I am sure.

---

No, it's not necessarily dependent on the word order.  You can say

> Двадцать человек сто**яло** в стороне. (example from [here](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.2))

Answer (score 3):

This is a singular vs plural predicative question, and it's a bit tricky.

From [gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo):

> На постановку сказуемого в форму единственного числа влияет стремление автора текста обратить внимание читателей на *пассивность* подлежащего, *совместность* действия действующих лиц, а также на *количество*, названное в подлежащем. Пассивность подлежащего может подчеркиваться употреблением в качестве сказуемых глаголов со значением бытия, наличия: быть, существовать, иметься и др.

That is, you *may* use singular to emphasize that you think of all these people as a whole. So here we have:

> 25 сотрудников *работают* в нашей компании --> 25 persons *work* in our company
>   В нашей компании *работает* 25 сотрудников --> *A total of* 25 persons *work* in our company

Note that English verb is still plural in the 2nd example, but Russian verb is singular.

On the matter of "quasi-passive" singular predicative, it's a sort of equivalent to English "There are". Consider this:

> В комнате *были* три человека --> Three persons *were* in the room
>   В комнате *было* три человека --> *There were* three persons in the room

You also may use the verbs different from "to be", e.g.:

> На полу *лежало* три человека --> *There were* three persons *lying* on the floor

But it's a bit less advisable.

Comment: About  gramota.ru, my advise, do not go for them. Сайт обладает тем недостатком, что они фильтруют вопросы-ответы, не публикуя **все** вопросы. Те вопросы, которые *могли бы* указать на противоречия, или на некорректность вопросов в некоторых их тестах, или в правилах, то есть, то, что мы называем *"возражение по сути"*, попросту никому не видны. Мои вопросы, к примеру, никому не видны, и были оставлены без ответа. А если кто-то не оставил возможности для опровержения, это значит, он использует антинаучный, закрытый, менторский, корпоративный стиль.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are possible, but the optimal word choice may depend on context (accent on personal details or on abstract quantity). *Plural/singular* verb versions focus on *noun/numeral* here.

('there **are** 25 employees, namely:')

```
В нашей компании работают 25 сотрудников: (1) Иван Петров... (25) Елена Сазонова.
```

(employee count **is** 25; the alternate word order is also possible in this version)

```
В нашей компании работает 25 сотрудников - это больше, чем в компании нашего партнёра. 

25 сотрудников работает в нашей компании, ещё 20 - в компании нашего партнёра.
```